# Cannot resolve work items in Team Foundation Services

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

Using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

I'm trying to do a checkin to TFS Online that resolves a work item. When I do the check in I should be able to "Resolve" the item as shown here

[image]

However I'm only getting the option to "Associate" the item.

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Is it a bug or a different type of work item?

Comment: It's a product backlog item. I just went ahead and created a bug and tried to check that in and still no option to "Resolve".

Answer (score 2):

For **Scrum** template, the "Resolved" option is not for Produce Backlog items. But **Tasks** have the "Resolved" option. 
For **Bug** in Scrum, if you choose '**Bugs appear on the backlogs and boards with tasks**', you could see the "Resolved" option when check in. If you choose '**Bugs appear on the backlogs and boards with requirements**', you also can't see the "Resolved" option like PBI.

[image]

**In Agile and CMMI template, the "Resolved" option shows or not depends on if there exists a Transition from the current state to "Resolved" state.**

For example: create a Requirement(named A) workitem in CMMI team project, check in and add A, you will find that there's no "Resolved". Then change the state of A to "Active" and add A again when check in, you will find that the "Resolved" option shows up. This is because there's no transition from "Proposed" to "Resolved" state. There's a transition from "Active" to "Resolved" state.